# Finding $ \int_0^1 \frac {\ln x}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

Today I encountered the problem of how to find $$ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac {\ln x}{1 + x^2}\mathrm dx $$ but got no start on it. Is this one of those integrals which we have to approach from the definite aspect only? [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln%28x%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29+dx) suggests that the indefinite version is miserable.

Thank you!

Comment: Is contour integration allowed? Or only real methods?

Comment: This integral has been done many times on this site.  Taylor expand the denominator, use the fact that $$\int_0^1 dx \, x^{2 k} \log{x} = -\frac1{(2 k+1)^2}$$ and sum.

Comment: I don't think it's needed.

Comment: this integral gives the Catalan constant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use integration by parts to get $$ \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac {\ln x}{1 + x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \left[ \arctan(x) \ln(x) \right]_0^1 - \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac {\arctan(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = - \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac {\arctan(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$Now, we use the Taylor expansion of $\arctan(x)$ to get $$ -\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\,\mathrm{d}x $$Switch the sum and the integral and it should be easy to end at the result $ -\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} $.

This is now the [Catalan constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Comment: What is "the $n$th Catalan constant"?

Comment: @Sasha Oops, typo. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

let $-I = \int_0^1{\ln x \over 1 + x^2} \ dx.$  we will need $$a_k = \int_0^\infty xe^{-kx}\ dx = {1 \over k^2} \int_0^\infty xe^{-x} \ dx = {1 \over k^2}$$

$I =  \int_0^1{\ln x \over 1 + x^2} \ dx,$ by a change of variable
$ u = -\ln x, x = e^{-u}, $ the integral

$\begin{eqnarray} I &=& \int_0^\infty{ ue^{-u} \over 1 + e^{-2u}} \ du \\
&=& \int_0^\infty ue^{-u}\left(1 - e^{-2u} + e^{-4u}+ \cdots \right) du\\
&=& a_1 - a_3 + a_5 + \cdots \\
&=&1 - {1 \over 3^2} + {1 \over 5^2} -{1 \over 7^2}+ \cdots = 0.9159\cdots=
\mbox{ Catalan constant}
\end{eqnarray}$

p.s.: i just learned the name for this constant.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx&=\int_0^{1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\, x^{2n}\ln x\;\mathrm dx\tag1\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^{1} x^{2n}\ln x\;\mathrm dx\tag2\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\tag3\\
&=\bbox[5pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large-\text{G}}}
\end{align}

---

**Explanation :**
$(1)\;$ Use series expansion $\;\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+y}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \,y^{n}$ and replace $y=x^2$
$(2)\;$ Use formula $\;\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^n \ln^k x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^k\, k!}{(n+1)^{k+1}}$, for $\  k=0,1,2,\cdots$
$(3)\;$ Series expression of [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
=\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - \ic x}\,\dd x
=\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{-\ic\bracks{\ic x}} \over 1 - \ic x}
\,\pars{\ic\,\dd x}
=\Im\int_{0}^{\ic}{\ln\pars{-\ic x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\Im\bracks{\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}
-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{-\ic x}\right\vert_{\, 0}^{\,\ic}
+\int_{0}^{\ic}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}
=-\,\Im\int_{0}^{\ic}\Li{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
=-\,\Im\Li{2}\pars{\ic}
\\[5mm]&=-\,\Im\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{n} \over n^{2}}
=-\,\Im\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{2n - 1} \over \pars{2n - 1}^{2}}
=-\,\Im\bracks{%
\ic^{-1}\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n - 1}^{2}}}
=-\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\Large-G}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{G}$ is the
>   [Catalan Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).